# Windows 10 Universal App C# - Run Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, windows-10, win-universal-app

I have a C# windows 10 app and I need to be able to run javascript. In .net I would use a WebView class to give me this ability but doesnt seem available in Native Windows 10 Universal App.

How would I be able to accomplish this?

Comment: I can only recommend the usage of the `Jint` Nuget-package at https://www.nuget.org/packages/Jint . Executing JavaScript is as easy as doing `object result = new JintEngine().Run("return 21 * 2");`. (https://jint.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Quick%20Start&referringTitle=Documentation)

Answer (score 2):

You can continue to use a Webview, like this:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <WebView />
</Grid>
```

Or you can give a try to ChakraBridge:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/eternalcoding/2015/10/21/using-javascript-frameworks-from-your-cuwp-application/

Thanks,